# Check if character is not a digit?

Tags: java

In my program, I need to check and see if characters are certain index's are digits. The condition I have set checks and decides if it's a digit

```
//Check to make sure all other characters are digits
        else if (Character.isDigit(militaryTime.charAt(0)))
        {
            System.out.println(militaryTime +
                " is not a valid miliary time." );
        }
        else if (Character.isDigit(militaryTime.charAt(1)))
        {
            System.out.println(militaryTime +
                " is not a valid miliary time." );
        }
        else if (Character.isDigit(militaryTime.charAt(3)))
        {
            System.out.println(militaryTime +
                " is not a valid miliary time." );
        }
        else if (Character.isDigit(militaryTime.charAt(4)))
        {
            System.out.println(militaryTime +
                " is not a valid miliary time." );
        }
```

However, I realized the problem when I run it, it says that times that are supposed to be valid, aren't. That's when I realized, it's checking to see if the index is a digit and if so it's returning that the time isn't valid.

How can I make it so that it checks if it is NOT a digit and thus displays the incorrect output, else it just moves on? I tried isLetter, but that just crashed my program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
if (!Character.isDigit(whatever))
```

And if you want something really simple to use - use a regular expression: `^\d{4}$` is the regexp for exactly four digits.

**Update:** to catch invalid hours, you'll need a more complicated regexp. `^([01]\d\d\d|2[0-3]\d\d)$`, or use Javas `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: Better yet, `SimpleDateFormat` with pattern `HHmm`.

Comment: You're right, the regexp doesn't catch invalid hours.

Answer (score 0):

Use `!` in front of the expression for the `if` statment; `!` means "not":

```
// if militaryTime.charAt(0) is not a digit
if (!Character.isDigit(militaryTime.charAt(0))) {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Not only that, but since they're not returning, processing also continues even after the check.